# Within Vue v-if, How do I check if an object within an array of objects has a specific value for a specified key?

Tags: vue.js

Subset of Code in .Vue File :

```
<div v-if="??"></div>
```

Subset of Code in .Vue File :

```
data() {
        return {
            form: {
                taken_test: '',
                current_income: '',
                gmat_score: '',
                gpa: '',
                graduation_year: '',
                gre_score: '',
                illiquid_assets: '',
                immigration_status: '',
                income_1: '',
                income_2: '',
                income_3: '',
                liabilities: '',
                liquid_assets: '',
                total_mortgage: '',
                reports: [],
                email: '',
            },
            errors: {},
        }
    },
```

Within the reports array, I have several objects as shown below. For example:

```
reports: [
    {aid_amount: 500, university_id: 1, aid_qualification: 'merit-based' },
    {aid_amount: 400, university_id: 2, aid_qualification: 'need-based' },
    {aid_amount: 200, university_id: 16, aid_qualification: 'merit-based' },
    {aid_amount: 700, university_id: 23, aid_qualification: 'merit-based' },
    {aid_amount: 300, university_id: 100, aid_qualification: 'need-based' },
]
```

I need to display a  if at least one of these objects has aid_qualification: 'merit-based'
What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking I could have a computed() variable but I feel like there is a better way to do this and I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a computed property.

```html
<div v-if="hasAidQualification"></div>
```

```js
computed: {
  hasAidQualification() {
    return this.form.reports.some(
      ({ aid_qualification }) => aid_qualification === 'merit-based'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are correct. This is a good case for a computed property. You could also use a method or write some logic right in the template, but a computed property is really what you need. Something like:

```
{
  computed: {
    hasMeritBased() {
      const {reports} = this;
      return Boolean(reports.length && reports.filter(r => r.aid_qualification === 'merit-based').length);
    },
  },
},
```